# Javascript, toggle between open and close button to push content div in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

Context:

- an open modal/overlay fullscreen
- with parent scrolling disabled
- and overlay scrolling y enabled
- content push when the `open` button is clicked

Which works great.

But I can't get the reverse effect when `close` button is clicked: It's closing without the effect.

If anyone can help me on this. I really appreciate it. Thank you so much.

```js
var body = document.body,
  overlay = document.querySelector('.modalbox'),
  overlayBtts = document.querySelectorAll('button[class$="modalbox"]');

[].forEach.call(overlayBtts, function(btt) {

  btt.addEventListener('click', function() {

    /* Detect the button class name */
    var overlayOpen = this.className === 'open-modalbox',
      overlayClose = this.className === 'close-modalbox';
    /* Toggle the aria-hidden state on the overlay and the 
       no-scroll class on the body */
    overlay.setAttribute('aria-hidden', !overlayOpen);
    overlay.classList.toggle('modalbox-active', overlayOpen);
    overlay.classList.toggle('modalbox-active-reverse', overlayClose);
    body.classList.toggle('noscroll', overlayOpen);


    /* On some mobile browser when the overlay was previously
       opened and scrolled, if you open it again it doesn't 
       reset its scrollTop property */
    overlay.scrollTop = 0;

  }, false);
});
```

```css
.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modalbox {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 50;
}

.modalbox-active {
  animation: ease slideright .4s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes slideright {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.modalbox-active-reverse {
  width: 0;
  animation: ease slideleft .4s 1 reverse;
}

@keyframes slideleft {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

[aria-hidden="true"] {
  display: none;
}

[aria-hidden="false"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" class="open-modalbox" id="trigger">OPEN</button>
</div>

<section class="modalbox" aria-hidden="true">
  <div>
    <h2>Hello, I'm the overlayer</h2>
    ...
    <button type="button" class="close-modalbox">CLOSE</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".modalbox").hide();
  $("#trigger").on("click", function(){
    $(".modalbox").show();
  });
});
var body = document.body,
  overlay = document.querySelector('.modalbox'),
  overlayBtts = document.querySelectorAll('button[class$="modalbox"]');

[].forEach.call(overlayBtts, function(btt) {

  btt.addEventListener('click', function() {

    /* Detect the button class name */
    var overlayOpen = this.className === 'open-modalbox',
      overlayClose = this.className === 'close-modalbox';
    /* Toggle the aria-hidden state on the overlay and the 
       no-scroll class on the body */
    overlay.setAttribute('aria-hidden', !overlayOpen);
    overlay.classList.toggle('modalbox-active', overlayOpen);
    overlay.classList.toggle('modalbox-active-reverse', overlayClose);
    body.classList.toggle('noscroll', overlayOpen);


    /* On some mobile browser when the overlay was previously
       opened and scrolled, if you open it again it doesn't 
       reset its scrollTop property */
    overlay.scrollTop = 0;

  }, false);
});
```

```css
.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modalbox {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 50;
}

.modalbox-active {
  animation: ease slideright .4s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes slideright {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.modalbox-active-reverse {
  width: 0;
  animation: ease slideleft .4s 1;
}

@keyframes slideleft {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" class="open-modalbox" id="trigger">OPEN</button>
</div>

<section class="modalbox" aria-hidden="true">
  <div>
    <h2>Hello, I'm the overlayer</h2>
    ...
    <button type="button" class="close-modalbox">CLOSE</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Use JQUERY to hide the modal on load and when the user clicks the button open the window. also needed to remove the CSS code below.

```css
[aria-hidden="true"] {
  display: none;
}

[aria-hidden="false"] {
  display: block;
}
```